# Placing text on a CSS trapezoid

Tags: css

I have inherited a legacy app for a rewrite and have run across a curious problem.  There is tabular data displayed on the page where the title of the table is within a trapezoidal shape that resembles a manila envelope tab.  At the bottom of such tables, there is usually a button row that is the same shape as the table title but rotated 180°.  Currently, this effect is being pulled off by using a square image with a white triangle in one half on a transparent background as a background image in the corner of a rectangular block to achieve the look of a trapezoid.  However, this technique is prone to flickering when the page is refreshed.

As an exercise, I have tried to see if I can replace this with a pure CSS technique.  I found this [link](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) to different shapes in CSS and have emulated the trapezoid to look as I need.  I am able to place the table title text within a trapezoid correctly.  However, when I need the look of the 180° rotated trapezoid, I am unable to get the text to place within the shape.  My code is included below and here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJPfG/) showing what I have accomplished so far.  I understand that the text shows below the rotated trapezoid because the height is set to 0 and I'm using border-top to build the shape.  Is there anything I can do to get this to work correctly?

Please keep in mind that I need this to display in IE8 (and possibly also IE8 in compatibility mode -- IE7).  Also, I'd like to keep additional HTML elements to a minimum because I want to keep this as semantic as possible.  I know I can place a span inside the div and absolutely position that span so that it displays the text within the shape, but when I do that I have to manually set a width on the trapezoid and when the width can vary from button row to button row, I'd rather not go down that path.

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="trap">Title Text</div>
<div class="trap180">Button Row</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.trap {
    color: black;
    font: normal bold 13px Arial;
    border-bottom: 27px solid #F00;
    border-right: 27px solid transparent;
    height: 0px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 27px;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.trap180 {
    clear: both;
    color: black;
    font: normal bold 13px Arial;
    border-top: 27px solid #F00;
    border-left: 27px solid transparent;
    height: 0px;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    line-height: 27px;
    padding: 0px 4px 0;
}​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with pseudo-elements. But I don't have access to those old browsers to test.

```
.trap, .trap180 {
    color: black;
    font: normal bold 13px Arial;
    float: left;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    background: salmon;
    position: relative;
}

.trap180 {
    float: right;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.trap:after,.trap180:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    width: 40px;
    top: 0;
}
.trap:after {
    right: -30px;
    border-bottom: 30px solid salmon;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    z-index: -10;
}
.trap180:after {
    left: -30px;
    border-top: 30px solid salmon;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    z-index: -10;
}
​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HJPfG/1/)

Frankly, if you need to still support IE7, I would just use images or allow a little graceful degradation.

Comment: Unfortunately, IE7 doesn't support the :before and :after pseudo-elements. Maybe graceful degradation for IE7 using images is the way to go.